# SVG Whitespace & CSS

Tags: html, css, svg, whitespace

Following example given:

http://jsfiddle.net/fKy2r/

How can I remove the whitespace between the div's border and the checkbox?

Also, as seen in the example, color changes with css are possible if using svg directly in html. When following code is used:

```
<object class="svg" type="image/svg+xml" data="checkbox.svg"></object>
```

Color changes are no longer possible with the external css file. IS there a chance to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `viewBox` attribute of the `svg` element, try with `80 80 350 350`, it's not perfect because the path doesn't use integer coordinates, you'd better redraw the path using non-fractional coordinates.

If you include the image via the `object` element, it's loaded in a way that the CSS can't affect its content.